# Simple example of pgfmath

Tags: pgfmath

I'm trying a small educational example using `pgfmath`. I want to calculate the minimum of a list of numbers.

More accurately, I have a list of (number,string)-pairs, and I want the minimum of all the numbers.

My `\calculateMin` command (see below) first uses a `\foreach` loop to build up a temporary list comprising just the first components. It then takes the minimum of that using `pgfmath`'s built-in `min` function.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\calculateMin[1]{%
  \def\mylist{}%
  \foreach \i/\j in {#1} {%
    \edef\mylist{\mylist,\i}%
  }%
  \pgfmathparse{min(\mylist)}\pgfmathresult%
}

Minimum of (8/ignore,7/this,2/second,5/component) 
is \calculateMin{8/ignore,7/this,2/second,5/component}.

\end{document}
```

### Result

> Minimum of (8/ignore,7/this,2/second,5/component) is 16383.0.

The result should be "2". What's going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because you're calling `min` with an argument it's not made for: The first element of your list is empty, which sets `\pgfmathresult` to the largest allowable number, due to the way the algorithm is implemented.

To get the correct behaviour, you should make sure the first component is not empty (the last one may be, though). Also, `\foreach` introduces groups, so the macro won't actually be updated if you only use `\edef`. Use `\xdef` (an alias for `\global\edef`) instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\calculateMin[1]{%
  \def\mylist{}%
  \foreach \i/\j in {#1} {%
    \xdef\mylist{\i,\mylist}%
  }%
  \pgfmathparse{min(\mylist)}\pgfmathresult%
}

Minimum of (8/ignore,7/this,2/second,5/component) 
is \calculateMin{8/ignore,7/this,2/second,5/component}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very satisfying explanation. Thank you very much Jake.